# How to create a neural network with one hidden layer of perceptron neurons and one hidden layer of radial basis neurons in matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

-- Hello, everyone,

I need to create a neural network with one hidden layer of perceptron neurons and one hidden layer of radial basis neurons in matlab using feedforwardnet.

I know that i can change the transfer function of the layers and make one layer with hyperbolic tangent transfer function and other with radial basis transfer function.

net2.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'tansig';

net2.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'radbas';

However, change the transfer function for a radial basis one, don't make the neuron be a radial bases neuron. Like say in the matlab documentation: "Notice that the expression for the net input of a radbas neuron is different from that of other neurons. Here the net input to the radbas transfer function is the vector distance between its weight vector w and the input vector p".

And even when using the radbas transfer function (in feedforwardnet) the input of the layer have a sum and not a product, like in radial basis neurons (look the picture).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYBtX.png)

Please, someone knows how to help me?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've understand your explanation, but it's not exactly what i need. Searching in the internet, i've discovered that you can change the neuron input with the command net.inputWeights{i,j}.weightFcn. I've changed it for euclidian distance with 'dist'.  Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, assumed this structure input layer, RBF layer, classical layer and output layer. Training will have two stages

- uncontrolled- aplication Kohonen rule on RBF neurons and clusters finding
- controlled- aplication error backpropagation on output and classical layer. Important backprop will not aplied on RBF neurons.

[My repository](https://github.com/Viceriel/Neuro-Fuzzy). This is my repository with Matlab implementation of RBF network, you found here Kohonen rule and heuristick for dispersion of Gaussian. I hope this will help.